# Hibernate Criteria: adding additional restriction to Restrictions.isEmpty

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have created a Hibernate (3.5) Criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = db.getSession().createCriteria(Vendor.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isEmpty("models"));
```

When executed with Criteria.list, Hibernate produces the following SQL (simplified for sake of readability):

```
SELECT this_.*
FROM   VENDOR this_
       left outer join MODEL models1_
         ON this_.id = models1_.VENDOR_ID
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   MODEL
                   WHERE  this_.id = VENDOR_ID)
```

What I'd like to do is add a restriction within the "not exists" part so that the SQL query would look like this


`SELECT this_.* FROM VENDOR this_
left outer join MODEL models1_
         ON this_.id = models1_.VENDOR_ID
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM   MODEL
                             WHERE  this_.id = VENDOR_ID AND DEPRECATED = 0 )`

Is that possible using the Hibernate Criteria API and if yes, how? Or is there some other possibility to achieve the same result (but still using Criteria API)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using a subquery:

```
Criteria criteria = db.getSession().createCriteria(Vendor.class, "vendor");

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Vendor.class, "vendor2");
dc.createAlias("vendor2.models", "model");
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("model.deprecated", 0));
dc.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("vendor2.id", "vendor.id"));
dc.setProjection(Projections.id());

criteria.add(Subqueries.notExists(dc));
```

which is the equivalent of the following HQL query:

```
select vendor from Vendor vendor
where not exists(select vendor2.id from Vendor vendor2
                 inner join vendor2.models model
                 where model.deprecated = 0
                 and vendor2.id = vendor.id)
```