# How to use createAlias for a null Set Attribute with Hibernate Criteria Api?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity Car that has a nullable set of vignettes , and i want to get the Car list that haven't a vignette.

i tried with this but i don't find my way ...

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Car.class);
criteria.createAlias("vignettes", "V");
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.lt("V.vignetteDateFin", dateDebut),Restrictions.eq("V.vignetteDateFin", null)))
```

can you suggest any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Car.class);
criteria.createAlias("vignettes", "V");
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.lt("V.vignetteDateFin", dateDebut),
    Restrictions.isNull("V"))
);
```

If this does not do what you want you may need a subquery. See this related question: [Hibernate Criteria: adding additional restriction to Restrictions.isEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549478/hibernate-criteria-adding-additional-restriction-to-restrictions-isempty)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem.

Replace this line :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
Restrictions.lt("V.vignetteDateFin", dateDebut),
Restrictions.isEmpty("V"))
```

by this one :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
Restrictions.lt("V.vignetteDateFin", dateDebut),
Restrictions.isNull("V"))
```